# Adjust the horizontal space between English and inline math

Tags: spacing

I have a code in my document:

```
(blah blah blah)\\
$\because P$ on $AB$ dddddd,$\therefore m_{AP}=m_{AB}\Rightarrow\frac{\beta-y_1}{\alpha-x_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{(\frac{-a}{b}x_2-\frac{c}{b})-(\frac{-a}{b}x_1-\frac{c}{b})}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{-a}{b}$\\
(blah blah blah)\\
```

which the code is included in a minipage environment.

And the output looks like this:[image]

Clearly, the space (see the red underline) between the texts and the inline math are too wide. How can I shrink it? I think it is not related to the `\medmuskip` or `\thickmuskip` commands.

Comment: Short answer: Seems you are using inline math to fake left aligned display math. If so, you should use left aligned display math instead, e.g., using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) or `mathtools`. Otherwise: In justified context also the spaces between several inline math code will be expanded to justify the text. Use either ragged right text, e.g., with environment `flushleft`, or displayed math.

Comment: Yes, I had set a `\everymath{\displaystyle}` command in premble.

Comment: @Schweinebacke After trying `flushleft`, the typeset is what I want. Thanks. But I still don't know the mechanism why spaces between several inline math code will be expanded to justify the text, isn't my default typeset already `flushleft`? And how can I limit the space not become too wide?

Comment: @Eric Avoid `\everymath{\displaystyle}`.

Comment: `\displaystyle` is not displayed math, but only the basic size of displayed math. Please read the manual of `amsmath` (link in my last comment). Whether or not your default is ragged right or justified cannot be determined without minimal working example.